# Build Object Recursive

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

I have a Object which looks like the following **obj**.

```
var obj = [
  { id: 1, name: "animals" },
  { id: 2, name: "animals_cat" },
  { id: 3, name: "animals_dog" },
  { id: 4, name: "animals_weazle" },
  { id: 5, name: "animals_weazle_sand shadow weazle" },
  { id: 11, name: "fruits" },
  { id: 32, name: "fruits_banana" },
  { id: 10, name: "threes" },
  { id: 15, name: "cars" }
];
```

The Object should be converted into the following scheme:

```
var items = [
    { id: 11, name: "fruits", items: [
      { id: 32, name: "banana" }
      ]},
    { id: 10, name: "threes" },
    { id: 1, name: "animals", items: [
        { id: 2, name: "cat" },
        { id: 3, name: "dog" },
        { id: 4, name: "weazle", items: [
            { id: 5, name: "sand shadow weazle" }    
        ]}
    ]},
    { id: 15, name: "cars" }
];
```

I tried a lot but unfortunately without any success. I did *$.each* on *obj*, did a *split('_')* on it and pushed it to items. But how can I do it for unlimited depth and push it into the right category?

I'm happy for any help.

Comment: Post some attempts at solving the problem and perhaps someone may help you.

Comment: Considering that you're changing the structure to something more treelike, there's little reason to keep the same ID.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: @Rollo that doesn't make sense if they are stored in a database with id as key

Comment: What if there is an element that has a parent `name` that is not existent in your array - how should an id be found for it?

Comment: @Bergi, `id` looks like an additional information for the element. for the tree building the `id` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps.

It works with `Array.prototype.forEach` for processing `obj`, `Array.prototype.reduce` for getting the right branch and `Array.prototype.some` for the right array element for inserting the new object.

This proposal works for sorted and consistent data.

```js
var obj = [
        { id: 1, name: "animals" },
        { id: 2, name: "animals_cat" },
        { id: 3, name: "animals_dog" },
        { id: 4, name: "animals_weazle" },
        { id: 5, name: "animals_weazle_sand shadow weazle" },
        { id: 11, name: "fruits" },
        { id: 32, name: "fruits_banana" },
        { id: 10, name: "threes" },
        { id: 15, name: "cars" }
    ],
    tree = [];

obj.forEach(function (a) {
    var path = a.name.split('_'),
        o = {};
    o.id = a.id;
    path.reduce(function (r, b) {
        o.name = b;
        r.some(function (c) {
            if (c.name === b) {
                c.items = c.items || [];
                r = c.items;
                return true;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, tree).push(o);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Update: Version for independent order of items.

```js
var obj = [
        { id: 5, name: "animals_weazle_sand shadow weazle" },
        { id: 32, name: "fruits_banana" },
        { id: 1, name: "animals" },
        { id: 2, name: "animals_cat" },
        { id: 3, name: "animals_dog" },
        { id: 4, name: "animals_weazle" },
        { id: 11, name: "fruits" },
        { id: 10, name: "threes" },
        { id: 15, name: "cars" },
        { id: 999, name: "music_pop_disco_euro"}
    ],
    tree = [];
    
obj.forEach(function (item) {
    var path = item.name.split('_'),
        o = tree;

    path.forEach(function (a, i) {
        var oo = { name: a, items: [] },
            last = path.length - 1 === i,
            found = o.some(function (b) {
                if (b.name === a) {
                    if (last) {
                        b.id = item.id;
                        return true;
                    }
                    b.items = b.items || [];
                    o = b.items;
                    return true;
                }
            });
        if (!found) {
            if (last) {
                o.push({ id: item.id, name: a });                        
            } else {
                o.push(oo);
                o = oo.items;
            }
        }
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```